# Stored procedure alter need privilegies

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I want to alter my stored procedure

> Unable to retrieve information. Please check your privileges. For
>   routines (stored procedures and functions) you need SELECT privilege
>   to mysql.proc if you are not the owner of the routines.

I create this procedure before 2 days with this logged user! Today i try to edit somthing and i get this error. I dont have premission but am root on server!

I also check on `cpanel` and check all premissions `ALL PRIVILEGES` and again is the some!!!

Comment: Are you trying via command line? Can you consider using Workbench? Easier to configure and get things done. As per your question, MySQL has a peculiar way of seeing **users**... they are defined as <username>@<hostname>. So, if you are trying to access things with the wrong combination, you will get the error message as you show in your question.

Comment: Am using `SQLyog`

Comment: Don't know it. Sorry.

Comment: Could you run SHOW GRANTS FOR CURRENT_USER from SQLyog and see if you really have such privileges?